If $(X_n)$ is a martingale is $X_n+Y$ a martingale for deterministic $Y$
If $(X_n)$ is a martingale (with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{A}_n = \sigma(X_0,...,X_n)$ ) is $X_n+Y$ a martingale (with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma(X_0+Y,...,X_n+Y)$) for a deterministic $Y$ (meaning $Y$ is a.s. constant).
For constant $Y$ (i.e. $Y=a$) this is obviously true. However, since $Y$ is a.s. constant we cannot conclude that $\mathcal{A}_n = \mathcal{F}_n$ and thus cannot conclude that $E[X_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = X_n$.
Does the above even hold for $Y$ a.s. constant or do we need $Y$ to be constant? Any help would be appreciated.

Yes, this does hold with $Y$ a.s. constant.
In fact, we'll show it for any $Y$ independent of $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \dotsc)$ (which included a.s. constants, since they're independent of everything).
Recall that to show that $X_n + Y$ is a martingale, we need to show that $\mathbf{E}(X_n + Y | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = X_{n-1} + Y$, which is true when
$$
\mathbf{E}(X_n + Y; F_{n-1})
= \mathbf{E}(X_{n-1} + Y; F_{n-1})
$$
for all generators $F_{n-1}$ of $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$, which are the events $\{X_k + Y \leq x\}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n-1, x \in \mathbf{R}$.
To see this, notice that for any integrable function $g$, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ respectively, we have that
$$
\mathbf{E}g(X, Y)
= \int g(x, y) \,\mathrm{d}F_{(X, Y)}(x, y)
= \int g(x, y) \,\mathrm{d}F_X(x)\, \mathrm{d}F_Y(y)
= \int \mathbf{E}g(X, y) \,\mathrm{d}F_Y(y)
$$
Hence, for any $k\leq n-1$, since $Y = a$ a.s., we have that, since $Y$ is independent of $(X_n, X_k)$ and $(X_{n-1}, X_k)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(X_n + Y; X_k + Y \leq x)
&= \int \mathbf{E}(X_n + y; X_k + y \leq x) \,\mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
&= \int \mathbf{E}(X_{n-1} + y; X_k + y \leq x) \,\mathrm{d}F_Y(y) \\
&= \mathbf{E}(X_{n-1} + Y; X_k + Y \leq x),
\end{align*}
where the second equality follows from the fact that $\mathbf{E}(X_n + y | \mathcal{A}_{n-1}) = X_{n-1} + y$ and $\{X_k + y\} \in \mathcal{A}_{n-1}$.
But this is exactly what we need to show to conclude that $X_n + Y$ is a martingale.
